# Not sure how to apply isNull(x,0)

Tags: sql-server

In Microsoft SQL Server 2008, I want to do the following:

```
UPDATE dbo.Test SET
Earned=(
SELECT Points
FROM dbo.Answer
WHERE AnswerID = Guess_AnswerID
AND Correct=1
)
```

The problem is when correct=0, then the select is null and Earned needs to be 0 instead of null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add IsNull around any 2 expressions. You can also use Coalesce in this case.

```
UPDATE dbo.Test SET
Earned=IsNull((
    SELECT Points
    FROM dbo.Answer
    WHERE AnswerID = Guess_AnswerID
    AND Correct=1
), 0)
```

You may also be looking to sum all the points on each matching answer. If that's the case, you need to make it Sum(Points) instead of just Points.

```
UPDATE dbo.Test SET
Earned=IsNull((
    SELECT Sum(Points)
    FROM dbo.Answer
    WHERE AnswerID = Guess_AnswerID
    AND Correct=1
), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work if correct=0

```
 UPDATE dbo.Test SET
Earned=(
SELECT isnull(Points,0)
FROM dbo.Answer
WHERE AnswerID = Guess_AnswerID
)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s can we do this on mobile version?

Answer (score 0):

```
update t
set Earned=case a.Correct when 1 then a.Points else 0 end
from dbo.Test t
inner join dbo.Answer a on a.AnswerID = Guess_AnswerID
```